# Custom attribute in Twilio verb

Tags: twilio

I was looking into attributes of `Dial` verb. In `Dial` verb, we have an attribute `hangupOnStar`. So if we created a call using dial verb and set attribute `hangupOnStar` then in the middle of the call the user can hang up the call by pressing star (*) on his phone. And then next verb will get executed in the `twiml` response.

So my question is can we create our own custom attribute like `toHangupPress (some_key)`? I searched the web but didn't find any documentation in this regard.

Can we create custom attribute at any place in *Programmable Voice* of *Twilio*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot create custom properties for TwiML, so it is not possible to hang up with any other keypress when using [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial).

If you are doing other things, then you can use [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to take keypresses and react to them, however it's not possible to nest a `<Dial>` within a `<Gather>`.